# Change subelement with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a structure that looks like so

```
[
  [
    {
      "ID": "grp1-001",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp1-002",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp1-003",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp1-004",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp1-005",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp1-006",
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "ID": "grp2-001",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp2-002",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp2-003",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp2-004",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp2-005",
    },
    {
      "ID": "grp2-006",
    }
.......
```

what I need to get as a result of the modification is this

```
[
  [
    ["1", "grp1-001"],
    ["2", "grp1-002"],
    ["3", "grp1-003"],
    ["4", "grp1-004"],
    ["5", "grp1-005"],
    ["6", "grp1-006"],
  ],
  [
    ["1", "grp2-001"],
    ["2", "grp2-002"],
    ["3", "grp2-003"],
    ["4", "grp2-004"],
    ["5", "grp2-005"],
    ["6", "grp2-006"],
  ],
```

Which means I need to keep the external structure (outside array and an internal grouping) but convert the inner dict to an array and replace the "ID" key with a value (that will come from external source like `--argjson`). I am not even sure how to start - any ideas/resources are highly appreciated.

Comment: You mention taking in some external input, how does that affect your desired result? Ii seems like you're just taking pairs of the object index (1-based) in the array and the ID value.

Comment: that input will be an array of 6 elements (think like headers) that will replace numbers 1..6. That part I will figure out later, for now, static indices should work just file.

Comment: Is it based on the index of the element or the `001`, `002` suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're just taking the objects and transforming them to pairs of the index in the array and the `ID` value, you could do this:

```
map([to_entries[] | [.key + 1, .value.ID | tostring]])
```

https://jqplay.org/s/RBac7SPfdG

Using `to_entries/0` on an array gives you an array of key/value (index/value) pairs. You could then shift the indices by 1 and convert to strings.